# Adding Sitecore 7.5 to existing solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I am trying to add the Sitecore as a separate project to an existing .Net MVC project which is built in .net framework 4.5.1.I followed the below steps to do so.

1. Copied Images,Assets,Scripts,Fonts folders from the existing Sample.Web project in to the sitecore project (now the sitecore project is the startup project instead of Sample.Web)
2. Added reference of Sample.Web to the sitecore project
3. Copied Views Folder as well because Sample.Web is using MVC
4. Merged Packages.Config file from Sample.Web Project to the packages .config that we get from Sitecore.
5. Merged the Web.Config file to the one present in sitecore project
6. I upgraded the sitecore project to target framework 4.5.1 as the existing projects were using Framework 4.5.1 using the extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13

Now in the above steps please suggest me on the below:

1. Will there be any issue in upgrading Sitecore Project to 4.5.1?
2. Solution is building successfully however I get the below run time error 
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your solution uses a more recent version of System.Web.Http than Sitecore does. Some Sitecore code is trying to load the older version of the DLL which you have most likely overwritten with the newer version, thus the exception.

If my guess is correct, I would suggest you rework your solution to use the same assemblies as Sitecore.

Comment: :Thank you for your suggestion.I will try and rework again on my solution.Also can you please tell me about my point 6(i.e upgrading sitecore project to target framework 4.5.1),will that be fine?

Comment: MVC  5.1.0.0 and .Net 4.5.1 should be fine. Im currently working on a new 7.2 build using MVC  5.1.0.0 .Net 4.5.0. Your issue is most likely as mentioned above by Patrick.

Comment: @Jason:I was able to resolve above issue.But now when ever I browse the site,sitecore is only resolved and not the other MVC application that is also present in the solution along with the sitecore. So can you tell me how can i tweak the request so that on some condition(still thinking on the condition) sitecore is not resolved and the mvc application is resolved ?